# magento 1.9 programmatically add / update record

Tags: magento-1.9, programmatically

What is the way to programmatically **Update** an existing record, and **Add** a new one if the record is not found in Magento 1.9?

I have the following code, and what I want it to do is to **add** a new address to a customer, and **update** the address if it's found by the *address_code*(a custom field). But right now the code always **Add** a new address, even if the address with the same *address_code* already found in the database.

```
    $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('address_code', $address_code)
        ->getFirstItem()
        ->addData($_custom_address)
        ->setCustomerId($customer->entity_id)
        ->save();
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below steps:

1. If you have created the $address_code as a customer attribute and set
   '`used_in_forms`' properly.

   ```
   $usedInForms = array(
       'customer_account_create',
       'customer_account_edit',
       'checkout_register',
       'adminhtml_customer'
   );


   $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
   ```
2. If the value of `$address_code` is being posted while update.

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
$query =  'INSERT INTO table (customer_id, address_code, first_name) VALUES(271, "87ui7","MAK" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE address_code="ASKIR", first_name="KAD";

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$writeConnection->query($query);
$writeConnection->closeConnection();
```

You'll have to set address_code as UNIQUE KEY. Using the above will update the rows if address_code exists else it will insert a new row.